# How to perform hough transform on canny edge image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, hough-transform, morphological-analysis

After some pre- processing, edge detection and thinning i got the following image and the image is of type double

[image]

and in order to remove the isolated pixels within regions i used dilation as

```
se90 = strel('line', 2, 90);
se0 = strel('line', 2, 0);
BWsdil = imdilate(Edge, [se90 se0]);
```

vertical dilation followed by horizontal dilation

Actually i want to segment the objects which is labeled within rectangle(ellipse-like structure).
[image]
It is noticed that the black rectangle are ruptured during dilation
if i increase the threshold i will lose the segment in the bottom rectangle.
If i'm proceed with this result i'm end up in an error and even basic segmentation algorithms are not working without preprocessing. please help

Can your suggest any other technique to improve mask
if i do connected component analysis on gradient image.i will get border of ellipse instead of ellipse as shown

i tried hough transform but i'm getting some bad results

```
close all;clear all
I=imread('Sub1.png');
load edge
rotI = imrotate(I,33,'crop');
[H,T,R] = hough(Edge);
imshow(H,[],'XData',T,'YData',R,...
            'InitialMagnification','fit');
xlabel('\theta'), ylabel('\rho');
axis on, axis normal, hold on;
P  = houghpeaks(H,25,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
x = T(P(:,2)); y = R(P(:,1));
plot(x,y,'s','color','white');
lines = houghlines(Edge,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);
figure, imshow(rotI), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
      xy_long = xy;
   end
end
```

[image]

Comment: The dilation is not a solution to delete the isolated components. As you have a binary image, the easiest solution is to perform a connected component labeling, and then to remove the small ones (according to a threshold).

Comment: I was saying that because you wrote "and in order to remove the isolated pixels within regions i used dilation as". The connecting component labeling replaces the dilation.

Comment: Not really, just an heuristic: as you are looking for really small components, I would delete the long ones in order to clean a little bit the image. Then I would try to look for the rectangular shapes (after filling).

Comment: how you extract rectangles

Comment: If you want to remove isolated pixels, use erosion followed by dilation.

Comment: He has only thin segments, an opening (erosion+dilation) will delete everything.

Comment: I thought again about your problem, and I think that you should probably decompose the process: segment the outer layers first (skin, fat, guts, etc.), then when you image if simpler, go for the disks.

Comment: You can try to train a CNN for each layer.